# Need newer version of netgen

Tags: software-installation

The repositories for Ubuntu/Kubuntu are listing `netgen-4.9.13.dfsg-8build2`.

This version does not work. Debian pulled it from their repository for that reason. There is a version `netgen-4.9.13.dfsg-11` that is available in Debian unstable that does work. I need a copy of the `-11` version. I tried to build for source code but had problems.

Is there one available for Ubuntu? Can I somehow install the Debian unstable version?

Answer (score 0):

#### Warnings:

- Software in the unstable repo, are under active development with a minimal of testing. Thus, their use can cause stability issues. The software may also depend on other packages that are only available in the unstable repo.
- Although Debian and Ubuntu are both debian linux systems, The two have minor differences in kernel settings and some packages. Thus, cross-installing packages could cause stability issues and hard to trace problems.
- If you understand these risks, Debian packages can be installed on Ubuntu provided you can meet the dependencies.

#### Installing

- Download the packages from Debian.
- Open a terminal and navigate to the folder where you downloaded the packages.
- Run `sudo dpkg -i <file name>` to install the packages. Start with the dependencies first if there are any needed.

Comment: OK. I get that trying to install a Debian version will ( and did) turn into a nightmare. But there is the correct version in ubuntu bonic. Im using 17.04 (Zesty Zopus). How can I load the bionic version. I have my system  setup for universe and  multiverse .  It should be possible to install the bionic version. In debian, I would just put /unstable at the end of the apt-get command line. This doesn't work for Ubuntu. I tried Muon but that didn't work for me either. Help will be sincerely appreciated - Gary R

Comment: you have to download the package and dependencies (if needed). Or temporarily add the repo to your source list. If you add the repo, I would use `aptitude` to install so you can check all that is going to be changed before committing. Note: you may again run into a dependency nightmare since you are trying to backport from an unstable source that is two versions newer.